# Add image in email not as linked resource but should be visible in outlook

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I want to add image to email. I tried several ways the final solution I am having is to add image as linkedResource but it will increase the size of email and I don't want that as email is already having several attachments.I am using xslt file to get html body of email from XML input. I am adding the image as following

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

but somehow the image is shown as red cross in outlook client in microsoft office and in .mht file.Emails look fine in outlook webmail client and on different browsers.

If I see the network tab in browser after I open the mail in browser from outlook client in microsoft office the request can be seen for url 'http://placehold.it/350x150' but received bytes are zero and response is blank.

Is there any way to add image to email without using linkedResource?
Your help will be really great to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the image using base64 and add like this:

```
<img src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{encoded string}">
```

Where the {encoded string} part is a base64 encoding of image data. JPEG can be gif or whatever according to type of image.

Comment: I think @mehta doesn't want to embed the image because the size of the email will be increased.

Comment: @ycsun He just asked the alternative without including the image as a linkedResource rt. So its cool man.

Answer (score 0):

You could use embedded images.

```
<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />
```

More info here: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

PS. A while ago we have an problem with email rendering in different browsers and email clients. And storing images as described was the best solution (for images, ofc :)).

Comment: I think @mehta doesn't want to embed the image because the size of the email will be increased.

Comment: @ycsun Well, he said about attachments. Anyway, image data should be somehow  transfered. And I am gathering loading from external server is not an option.